# UnitTesting assembly.GetTypes() throws an exception in the build pipeline only

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, pipeline, assemblies

The unit tests calls the following method. It passes when run locally but fails when run as part of Azure DevOps build pipeline due to a LoaderException on assembly.GetTypes(). I'm not sure how to debug this because it doesn't happen locally. Normally I would run through this in debug mode and look at the LoaderException. The pipeline task VSTest@2 only logs the stacktrace

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
{
   if (assembly != null)
   { Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes(); }
}
```

```
   Test method 
Tests.Data.IBlockConversionTests.TestIBlockConversion threw exception: 
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  Stack Trace:
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Plugin.PluginLoader`1.LoadPlugins(IEnumerable`1 assemblies) in D:\a\1\s\Core\Plugin\Plugin\PluginLoader.cs:line 80
   at Tests.Data.IBlockConversionTests.TestIBlockConversion() in D:\a\1\s\Tests\Data\IBlockConversionTests.cs:line 42
```

Comment: Start by looking at the exception message of the `LoaderException`, and any `InnerExceptions`

Comment: How would I do this when running the unit test on a pipeline?

Comment: Is there a logging facility that is surfaced in this build pipeline system?

Comment: Look at your test output? Catch the exception and log everything you need? Create a dedicated console app which just reproduces the issue and prints what you need? Be imaginative!

Comment: Set Syste.Debug to true https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug to check if there would be sth interesting

Comment: @CBFT Hi there, is any updates for this issue? You can refer to Krzysztof Madej‘s comment. Set the variable system.debug to true and you will see the debug log just like you run through it in debug mode. If you have any further questions, please feel free to comment~

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to change the yaml pipeline by adding distributionBatchType: 'basedOnAssembly' as seen below. Turning on the diagnostics also fixed this issue, but was not an ideal solution.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\Tests\**
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: false
    distributionBatchType: 'basedOnAssembly'
```

Comment: This also fixed an issue we had on another pipeline where the VSTest was unable to find certain Dlls.

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: I realized it was likely a multithreading issue so I looked up how to reduce the number of threads.